# In Hartl's Rails Tutorial, what does the CSS for textarea refer to?

Tags: railstutorial.org

In section 5.1.2 one adds some custom CSS, including the following:

```
textarea {resize: vertical;}
```

but I can't find any textarea tags anywhere in the HTML. Is it tagged implicitly, or does this CSS just not refer to anything?

(A search of the [github](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/tree/master/app/views) doesn't turn up any hits for textarea outside of styling sheets.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a text_area field here, in the micropost form:

https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb

You were probably searching the repo for 'textarea', which yields no results as Rails uses form helpers. f.text_field, f.date_field etc

Comment: That must be it, I hadn't thought of the Rails helpers. At that point in the book that form hadn't been made yet, but since it was app-wide CSS, he must have been thinking ahead.

Comment: Yup sounds about right. Always good to know though to save pulling hair out!